# Cant get Innertexts from webpage using html agility pack xpath in c#

Tags: c#, web-scraping, xpath, html-agility-pack, windows-forms-designer

So this is my code guys.
Im trying to get the text inside a span and storage it locally. Im using html agility pack and trying to retrieve the text using xpath but the nodes dont retrieve anything and appear as null.

This is the page im trying to get the text from: https://siat.sat.gob.mx/app/qr/faces/pages/mobile/validadorqr.jsf?D1=10&D2=1&D3=15030267855_SDS150309FC7
Specifically the "Denominación o razón social" text.

```
namespace ObtencionDatosSatBeta
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable table;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        private void InitTable()
        {
            table = new DataTable("tabladedatosTable");
            table.Columns.Add("Variable", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Contenido", typeof(string));
            //table.Rows.Add("Super Mario 64", "84%");
            tabladedatos.DataSource = table;
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitTable();
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => web.Load("https://siat.sat.gob.mx/app/qr/faces/pages/mobile/validadorqr.jsf?D1=10&D2=1&D3=15030267855_SDS150309FC7"));
            var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"ubicacionForm: j_idt12:0:j_idt13: j_idt17_data\"]//tr//td//span");
            var innerTexts = nodes.Select(node => node.InnerText);
            
        }

        private void tabladedatos_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"ubicacionForm: j_idt12:0:j_idt13: j_idt17_data\"]//tr//td//span");
```

The line of code above is the one that appears as null.

Comment: How have you determined the ID of that element? Does it really contain spaces?

Comment: The HTML in the link you have posted, shows an ID (body of that Table) equal to `ubicacionForm:j_idt10:0:j_idt11:j_idt14_data`, which should return 6 nodes. -- You should probably load the `TD` nodes instead of the inner `SPAN`. -- Those IDs are probably dynamic. Find something that isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Xpath which gets the first span under the element with the following ID: ubicacionForm:j_idt10:0:j_idt11:j_idt14_data

```
(//*[@id='ubicacionForm:j_idt10:0:j_idt11:j_idt14_data']//span)[1]
```

You can select the element using multiple different ways by copying the HTML in chrome (Ctrl + Option + J)

[image]

And then paste the HTML in Xpather where you can play around with your Xpath. [Xpather.com](http://xpather.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The xpath route you provided worked! The thing is i really couldnt find it by myself? Thanks to that i now have all the 6 texts from that column and now i would like to get the 6 texts from the other column aswell. 

How did you know that was correct element id to use and wich id should i use to get the other column texts from that table?
I was going through the html but i never found ubicacionForm:j_idt10:0:j_idt11:j_idt14_data.
Im really new to this lol 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now that you mention it that ID might be dynamic (changes).However, to find the ID I opened the chrome dev tools. Clicked on the element toggle (the top right button), selected the element I wanted to inspect, and then viewed the HTML.

Comment: There is always more than 1 way to get an element. For instance you could use this which returns all the spans: '//tbody/tr/td//span' and use '(//tbody/tr/td//span)[0]' to get the 1st, '(//tbody/tr/td//span)[1]' to get the 2nd etc.